# How to select all rows where column contains ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all rows where column called "users" contains given User ID. Here is example:

---

```
    ID - users

     1 - 2,5,7,9,12,14

     2 - 3,7,8

     3 - 1,2,6,9
```

In this example I want to select rows with user with ID: 7.

Comment: what datatype is users - varchar?

Comment: It isn't table with users. In my case it's table with matches and each have list of users that played. I want to select all matches, where user with ID 7 payed in.

Comment: @Mackan, yes, VARCHAR(255).

Comment: @DudiKonfino, it's working now with Alex's solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I removed the noise from your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tblYourTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(7, users)>0 ;
```

Comment: Yeah! It's working! `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(7, users)` Thanks!